# Get values from dynamic inputs Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

i'd like to know how i can get the values from a dynamic input in Spring, a method that get the values, can someone explain me how to do that ?

This is my html and javascript input.

JSP

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" id="telefone" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero de telefone...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Adicionar
                                    </button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy hide">
    <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <input type="text" name="addmore[]" id="telefone" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero de telefone...">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remover
                                        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".add-more").click(function() {
        var html = $(".copy").html();
        $(".after-add-more").after(html);
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    });

    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you have somehow forgotten to post the spring part...

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: I wanna know how to do the method in spring, that's why i didn't post the spring part, that was my ask.